# How to open a modal in Ionic 5 automatically, just after loading of the page?

Tags: modal-dialog, ionic5

I'd like to open a modal in Ionic 5 just opening a page. Without any action, just load the page and hop! you get your modal.

I've been reading the documentation at https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#events but is too cryptic for me. Need some more elaboration...

I´ve fount severals examples out there of opening the modal with a click event, but that's not what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look into Ionic's [lifecycle hooks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle) which let you execute code at different moments during a component's existence. You'll probably want to call a modal creating method inside of the `ionViewDiDEnter` hook within the component where you want the modal to appear.

Something like this:

```
export class YourPage {

  constructor(public modalController: ModalController) { }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.presentModal();
  }

  async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: YourModalComponent
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }

}
```